# How to organize apache site configuration files

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I'm looking for a way to organize the files that makes up the apache sites-enabled configuration.

Let's say I have sites A, B and C on my webserver. These sites have different **DocumentRoot** s and different **RewriteRule** s as well as different Authentication requirements. Defined by **Alias** and **Directory** contexts. I'm on a debian based server.

I want both a **http** and **https** version of A, B and C.

For VirtualHost `ServerName www1.myhome.com;`, I want to serve A and B.

For VirtualHost `ServerName www2.myhome.com;`, I want to serve B and C.

**How do I avoid duplication of the configuration of A, B and C?**

I was trying to use includes in different forms. Including configuration for e.g. A into the different virtualhosts, but I found the problem with file paths cumbersome.  In particular it doesn't allow me to `a2ensite A`. Also it makes troubleshooting the configuration file a nuisance. This is all done as a part of migrating from Apache2.2 to Apache2.4.

Is there a good solution to this problem?

Configuration site A.  B and C are similar in structure.

```
Alias /A /srv/rootA/
<Directory /srv/rootA/>
   // Unique stuff for A
   // In particular Auth and rewrite rules
</Directory>
```

Comment: By "sites" I do you mean Virtual Hosts or just three directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It's one solution amongst many and I'm assuming you're on a debian based server.*

In your apache serverroot directory, create a directory `instances`. In this directory create as many config files as you have "sites" (A,B or C). Define in them what you need to and name each file accordingly.

In `sites-available` directory, create one file for each virtual host you need. In these files, define you virtual host as usual and include "sites" config as needed, ie:

```
# Vhost for www1.myhome.com
<VirtualHost *:80>

   Include instances/siteA.conf
   Include instances/siteB.conf

</VirtualHost>
```

After, you'll be able to do `a2ensite` and debug easier.

Ref on Apache include command : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include

Comment: Thanks this is useful.  How would I go about to `a2ensite siteA.conf`?

Comment: You won't, siteX.conf aren't seen as "sites" from apache POV. You'll do `a2ensite` on files present in sites-available directory.

Comment: I'm able to put instances in sites-available and `a2ensite instances/siteA`. The command works but gives warnings.  Not sure if I'll go that route though. Thanks for your insights.